# Qt GUI with OpenCV C API

Tags: c, qt, opencv, user-interface

Anyone knows whether opencv program written in C API can be used with Qt GUI? such as Qt creator Qt4.

I wish to display opencv program video in Qt GUI, but it is written in C API is it possible?
can anyone show me some examples?

Comment: You can use C code from C++ through `extern "C" { (...) }`. As for example: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/03/09/augmented-reality-with-qt-part-1-capturing-video-from-webcam .

Comment: i use the c++ api of openCV, thought it would have any functions in both apis